# phpMyAdmin: one table in database work, another doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I've created an app were you can register as a user. You can sign up and then you're in the database "myAppDataBase" in "firsttable". A second table contains a list of lets say other important users that I manually created in the PHPmyAdmin-Website/"App". This table is called "secondtable".

My code to get the data is as follows:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mydatabas";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //Print ("successfully connected");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM firsttable";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($query));

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $rows[] = $r;
    Print ("sf");
}
Print json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The only thing i changed was this line: THIS WORKS

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM firsttable";
```

But when I change it to this it won't work anymore.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM secondtable";
```

Any help?

Comment: And, _"it won't work anymore."_ means?

Comment: it works with with "firsttable" i get all the results. but with "secondtable" nothing turns out @nirrower

Comment: what do you mean with mysqli_error there should be any error, because the only thing I am changing is the table.

Comment: If anything fine than y not insert. Just because of any error. Y u don't want to chk?

Comment: Or just run second query in phpmyadmin manually

Comment: @devpro y u not use real words?

Comment: My friend I said... Please run this query in your phpmyadmin SELECT * FROM secondtable

Comment: @devpro it works in phpmyadmin. But it doesn't in the code. Any idea what could be a reason, that one table behaves and responds good and another one doesn't?

Comment: Alright and you didn't get any mysql error and php error right?

Comment: no i didn't get any errors

Comment: U didn't respond chk my answer

Comment: You said in the text the DB is called "myAppDataBase" but then in PHP code your DB is "mydatabas". Do you have multiple databases? Are you connecting to the right one?

Comment: What does `$num` contain? Are you sure the table isn't empty?

Comment: @b1tsh1ft I only have one database. I just didn't want to write the real name in here ;) and yes i am connecting the right on. Otherwise it wouldn't work with "firsttable"

Comment: @kba the table isn't empty..

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
mysqli_error($query)
```

With this:

```
mysqli_error($conn) // with your connection
```

**Explanation:**

`mysqli_error()` function needs connection link identifier not your query as param.

**[Mysqli_error PHP Manual](http://php.net/mysqli_error)**

Comment: I changed i but didn't get any answers. I think the code is not the Problem, but something is wrong with the second table but i don't know what..

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED IT! Somehow, my second wasn't encoded the right way. I simply added this coder and it worked:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');
```

Thanks for all you help though. ;)